# JQuery datepicker not rendering a calendar image after it is added dynamically as part of a partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, datepicker

I have a MVC Razor page in C# .Net Framework 3.5.

The page calls for the user to be able to add (flight) items dynamically when a "Add Fare" button is clicked.  The items are stored in a list in the overall model for the entire page.  When the button is clicked, I call some javascript that serializes the form (so I have access to the model), add a new item to the list in the model, and the item is represented in a partial which I then append to a div in the main page.

I have a problem, however, as I am making use of the JQuery datepicker, and whilst this functionally works ok (i.e. when you click into it, a calendar pops up and you can select a date), the actual calendar button is not being rendered next to my inputs?

Here is the form I am trying to add the partial view into..

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ManualFlight", "ShoppingBasket", FormMethod.Post, new {@class="manualFlightForm" }))
    {
        <div id="shoppingBasketManualFlight" class="whiteCanvas">
            <div class="ManualFlightDetails">
                <div class="ManualFlightFareContainer"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonPanel">
                <div>   
                    <a class="button borderlessButton" onclick="shoppingBasketAddFare(); return false;">Add Fare</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     }
```

This is the javascript I am calling from the onclick:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form.manualFlightForm').serialize(),
        url: "/ShoppingBasket/ShoppingBasketAddFare",
        cache: false,
        traditional: true
    }).done(function (responseHtml) {
        $(".ManualFlightFareContainer").append(responseHtml);

        $('.t2Datepicker').datepicker({
            minDate: '+1d',
            defaultDate: '+1d',
            changeMonth: true,
            buttonImage: '/App_Themes/Travel2/Images/calendar_icon.png',
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            maxDate: '+3y'
        }); 
        });
```

Note I am calling datepicker after I have rendered the response I receive back from my call to the controller..
This is the partial that is being added (please ignore the use of tables, I am trying to recreate something that already exists in another part of the site..

```
@model Travel2.WebUI.ViewModels.ShoppingBasket.ShoppingBasketManualFlightViewModel
<div class="shoppingBasketManualFlightFare">
    <table id="tblManualFlight">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Passenger Type</th>
                <th colspan="2">Departure Details</th>
                <th colspan="2">Arrival Details</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Flight No.</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Class</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Cost</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Sale Price</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Commission</th>
                <th rowspan="2">PEX</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>IATA</th>
                <th>Date & Time</th>
                <th>IATA</th>
                <th>Date & Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="paxType middle">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].PassengerType, ViewBag.PassengerTypes as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
            </td>
            <td class="iata">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].DepartureIATA)
            </td>
            <td class="dateTime">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].DepartureDate, new { Class="t2Datepicker" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].DepartureHour, ViewBag.Hours as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].DepartureMinute, ViewBag.Minutes as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
            </td>
            <td class="iata">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].DestinationIATA)
            </td>
            <td class="dateTime">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].DestinationDate, new { Class = "t2Datepicker" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].DestinationHour, ViewBag.Hours as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].DestinationMinute, ViewBag.Minutes as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
            </td>
            <td class="middle">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].FlightNumber)
            </td>
            <td class="middle">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].FlightClass)
            </td>
            <td class="middle">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].Cost)
            </td>
            <td class="middle">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].SalePrice)
            </td>
            <td class="middle">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].Commission)
            </td>
            <td class="middle">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fares[Model.Fares.Count - 1].PEX)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Just for completion, here is the method in the controller that handles adding a new instance to the model and returning back the partial view.

```
[HttpPost, STPAuthorize]
public ActionResult ShoppingBasketAddFare(ShoppingBasketManualFlightViewModel model)
{
    if (model.Fares == null)
    {
        model.Fares = new List<ShoppingBasketManualFlightFareViewModel>();
    }

    ViewBag.PassengerTypes = GetPassengerTypes();
    ViewBag.Hours = GetHours();
    ViewBag.Minutes = GetMinutes();
    model.Fares.Add(new ShoppingBasketManualFlightFareViewModel());
    return PartialView("ShoppingBasketAddFare", model);
}
```

Any ideas as to why the calendar image isn't rendering?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the `showOn` option.

From [buttonImage docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-buttonImage)

> A URL of an image to use to display the datepicker when the showOn
>   option is set to "button" or "both".

[showOn docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn)

```
$('.t2Datepicker').datepicker({
            minDate: '+1d',
            defaultDate: '+1d',
            changeMonth: true,
            buttonImage: '/App_Themes/Travel2/Images/calendar_icon.png',
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            maxDate: '+3y',,
            showOn:'both'
        });
```

Comment: Yup! Thanks! That seemed to do the trick, just need to style the button it renders within an inch of its life!